# Assigning the result of a begin-end-while block prevents the block from being executed

Tags: ruby

You can assign the result of a block to a variable:

```
a = begin
  1
end
a #=> 1
```

Meanwhile, `while` can be appended after a block like this:

```
begin
  puts "this will be printed once"
end while false
```

and it would be executed at least once. If you assign a variable to that `being-end-while` block, it doesn't get executed any more:

```
a = begin
  puts "this won't be printed at all"
end while false
```

Can somebody explain me what's going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add assignment, it is interpreted as:

```
(a = begin
  puts "this won't be printed at all"
end) while false
```

How about put parentheses around the `begin ... end while false`?

```
a = (begin
  puts "this won't be printed at all"
end while false)
# prints: this won't be printed at all
# a => nil
```

Comment: Still, this assignment would be executed at least once if I am correct?

Comment: @BroiSatse, It's not `begin ... end while ..` anymore. It's a `... while false` (inline while statement).

Comment: @BroiSatse, If you mean the second one, it prints the string.